# Python code doesn't run, I don't know what to do to fix it

Tags: python

```
class AQGraph:
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib as plt

    PrimaryA = pd.read_csv('PrimaryA.csv')  # Daily data from 12/1/19 to 4/16/20 from PrimaryA sensor
    PrimaryB = pd.read_csv('PrimaryB.csv')  # Daily data from 12/1/19 to 4/16/20 from PrimaryB sensor
    AverageData = np.mean(PrimaryA[:][2], PrimaryB[:][2])

    print(AverageData)
    plt.plot(PrimaryA[:][0], AverageData)
    plt.show()
```

Attached is my python code. I'm running it in Pycharm and for some reason the green arrow that pops up for Pycharm files isn't there. I've looked through my settings and I'm running Python 3.7. Any advice?

Comment: Instead of saying it wont run, perhaps try explaining why it wont run. What error do you get?

Comment: A question is expected to include actual output (or the text of the actual error you get instead, or otherwise a description of what it does *instead of* running, and enough details to let someone else produce the problem themselves (so minimal examples of any necessary input files, if you can't modify the code to not require them). See the [mre] page in the Help Center.

Comment: Also, your title should be narrowly descriptive of your specific problem. A title that would work for half the questions in the Python tag is not descriptive at all.

Comment: (also, what's with the start of a class definition with nothing indented under it? Note too that defining a class you never instantiate doesn't generally do anything useful).

Comment: Sorry, when I mean it doesn't run, I mean it doesn't have the green arrow that most Pycharm files have.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided, doesn't comply with python rules and standards.
there is a `class` in your code without any constructor or any method.
Also, you didn't follow Python's indentation policy. Based on what you provided, as soon as you try to run it you should see an error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
class AQGraph:

    @staticmethod
    def a_method():

        PrimaryA = pd.read_csv('PrimaryA.csv')  # Daily data from 12/1/19 to 4/16/20 from PrimaryA sensor
        PrimaryB = pd.read_csv('PrimaryB.csv')  # Daily data from 12/1/19 to 4/16/20 from PrimaryB sensor
        AverageData = np.mean(PrimaryA[:][2], PrimaryB[:][2])

        print(AverageData)
        plt.plot(PrimaryA[:][0], AverageData)
        plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    AQGraph.a_method()
```

In the command line try:

```
> python python_file.py
```

Comment: Sorry, the indentations didn't carry over from my code. When I go into Pycharm, the green arrow that allows you to run code isn't there for me. What do you mean that I don't have a constructor or a method? How could I change my code to have one?

Comment: Huh, for some reason it still doesn't work. I'm not given the option of running the code. Just for my understanding, def a_method(): creates the method, and then at the bottom of the code you call said method?

Comment: Yes, you should say which method you need to execute

Comment: Edited my previous comment

Comment: in the command line try: python your_python_file.py, I updated my answer

Comment: At least the green arrow pops up now, but now I'm getting an error. I can't copy and paste the whole thing, but its something about a key error?